# Tabs Ionic 4 Error en Dispositivo

Tags: ionic

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con Ionic 4. Usé la plantilla blank al momento de crear el proyecto y necesito manejar Tabs. En el emulador Web el redireccionamiento funciona pero cuando compilo la aplicación para el dispositivo en este caso android solo me aparece la pantalla inicial en la que tengo unos botones que me direccionan a otra página mediante `this.router.navigate(['/tabs/inicio/' + pagina]);`.

Así tengo el router.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'tabs', component: TabsPage, children: [
    { path: 'inicio', children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../inicio/inicio.module#InicioPageModule' },
      { path: 'seguro', children: [
        { path: 'tipo', loadChildren: '../seguro/seguro-tipo/seguro-tipo.module#SeguroTipoPageModule' },
        { path: 'listar/:id/:nombre', loadChildren: '../seguro/seguro-listar/seguro-listar.module#SeguroListarPageModule'},
        { path: 'ver/:id/:nombre', loadChildren: '../seguro/seguro-ver/seguro-ver.module#SeguroVerPageModule'}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/tabs/inicio', pathMatch:'full' }
];
```

Gracias por la ayuda.